# Webflux application, concurrent outgoing connections (theoretically, and configuration parameters)

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a Webflux application, which accepts incoming json requests and returns flux responses. Each request in turn initiates a request to a another micro-service using Webclient.

How many concurrent requests can such a webflux application handle, and how many concurrent requests can such a WebClient make? More importantly are there any reactor/netty/webflux configuration parameters that help in deciding the number of concurrent requests that can be processed.

The application is mostly I/O bound, and almost all of the latency is from the outgoing requests via webclient. It's a quad-core machine with 16GB RAM.

(edited) - I am basically looking to understand how many threads are generated, the threading model in such an application, and configuration parameters that Netty provides. Note - I am not looking to actually get throughput/latency numbers for my setup (I can, and have already load tested the application).

Comment: It's your application and your hardware, why don't you load test it? All numbers we can provide will just be guesswork, only you can get the _real_ numbers. [gatling](https://gatling.io/) might help you as a load testing tool.

Comment: @knittl - I have load tested it, and see that the throughput maxes out at 40 req/s, and it seems to be making 40 concurrent requests as well. I think this is more to do with configuration parameters and understanding what the theoretical amount of threads should be

Answer (score 0):

if you read the source code you find the following.

```
/**
 * Default max connections. Fallback to
 * available number of processors (but with a minimum value of 16)
 */
int DEFAULT_POOL_MAX_CONNECTIONS =

Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty(ReactorNetty.POOL_MAX_CONNECTIONS,
        "" + Math.max(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 8) * 2));
```

max connections are set by the parameter:

```
reactor.netty.pool.maxConnections
```

and if not set is defaulted to

> available number of processors (but with a minimum value of 16)

[ConnectionProvider](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.java) Here you will find more of the current default values.

[ReactorNetty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/netty/ReactorNetty.java) here you can find all defined parameters and their names.

But according to [this](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/951#issuecomment-577158136) post, the defaults will change in the release of 1.0.x of Netty to:

> 500 max connections
>
> 1000 pending acquire max count
>
> 45s pending acquire timeout

Here is that [commit](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/pull/966/commits/b68a0fd03f7fea4b7f400e4b1249a3e21dced1dd)